# Acessing Google Drive and Dropbox from java code and performing ls(list files) and cd (change directory) type operation

Tags: java, google-drive-api, dropbox-api

I have to build a project, in which I have to perform ls(list all files) and cd(change directory) type operation on Google Drive and Dropbox from java code. I have gone through the API for it,but could not find appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real equivalent of `cd` in the Drive API, but to list all files in a given folder you can perform a [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) request with a search query like `'1234567' in parents`, where '1234567' is the id of the folder:

https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters

Comment: I used the same code snippet given in link "file.list" but this line is showing error- import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList that FileList is not resolved as type

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of the Java library, FileList is a valid type: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/

Comment: Likewise, there isn't any 'cd' in the Dropbox API, but you can list and search for files: https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-java-sdk-1.5.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#metadata(java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.String)
https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-java-sdk-1.5.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#search(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, boolean)

Comment: during accessing google drive, I am able to list that files only which is uploaded by particular app which's credentials are used (CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRECT). Is there any way in GDrive, like Dropbox that we can list all files and folders of it and navigate to different directories by using any app's credentials.